# The tangent space to graph ($f$) is the graph of $df_x:T_x(X) \rightarrow T_{f(x)}(Y)$

Tags: calculus

> (b) Prove that the tangent space to graph ($f$) at the point $(x,f(x))$ is the graph of $df_x:T_x(X) \rightarrow T_{f(x)}(Y).$

My attempt is to show that the image of the map $d(x,f(x))$ is
$$\{(x,df(x)) \;|\; df_x:T_x(X) \rightarrow T_{f(x)}(Y)\}$$

And I claim that $d(x,f(x)) = (x,df(x))$  - is that correct? I am under the impression that $dx(x) = 1(x) = 1$ or somehow.

And then it seems the proof is complete?

P.S. The previous question and my proof:

> (a) Suppose that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a smooth map, and let $F: X \rightarrow X \times Y$ be $F(x) = (x,f(x))$. Show that
>   $$dF_x(v) = (v, df_x(v)).$$

\begin{eqnarray*}
dF_x(v) &=& \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{F(x + tv) - F(x)}{t}\\
& = & \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{(x+tv, f(x+tv)) - (x,f(x))}{t}\\
& = & \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{(tv,f(x+tv)-f(x))}{t}\\
& = & \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} (v,\frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t})\\
& = & (v,df_x(v)).
\end{eqnarray*}

Thank you.